# How to get element(TAG) value from XML that is stored as [XML NULLABLE] in a table in DB2

Tags: java, xml, db2

I am storing xml in a column in a table as [XML Nullable] in DB2. 
The table has other columns also, most of them are String. Now I have to fetch the value of an element inside the stored XML.

For Example:

> ```
>       Suppose the table name is : REGEVENT
>                      Columns are: REFID (VARCHAR), APPID(VARCHAR), DATA(XML NULLABLE)
> ```

suppose I am storing following in DATA column.

```
         <Employee>
            <Name>huff</Name>
         </Employee>
```

Now I have to get the value of Name from that XML. How to get that value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can be done in 1 step. (Probably with a complicated query you can do this.)

But normally you should do this in 2 steps:

1. Query the DB for the DATA column
2. Parse the xml for the Name element using one of the libraries described [here (DOM, SAX, ...)](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/parsing-xml-using-dom-sax-and-stax-parser-in-java.html).

Comment: When I query the DB for DATA column and try to cast it to String.. then I get the following exception:  java.lang.ClassCastException, CaughtExceptionMessage:com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ie cannot be cast to java.lang.String.

Comment: That's because the XML data type is not a String. You should look at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0610kokkat/index.html?S_TACT=105AGY75